# Using shouldjs to check values in an unordered array

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, express, should.js

I have an express.js application where I am using supertest and should.js for my testing framework. I'm having trouble testing for values in an unordered array.

[According to the should.js documentation, the .any function would work here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should#-any) Any thoughts on how to get it to work would be greatly appreciated.

### Expected Response

```
{data: [
  {username:"Test User 3", ...},
  {username:"Test User 6", ...}
]}
```

### Attempted Validation Calls

```
response.body.data.any.username.should.equal("Test User 3");
response.body.data.any.username.should.equal("Test User 6");
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [containDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should#-containdeep-othervalue-):

```
response.body.data.should.containDeep([{ username: "Test User 3" }]);
response.body.data.should.containDeep([{ username: "Test User 6" }]);
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the pointer. I think you're missing array brackets around the objects. So it should come out to be: response.body.data.should.containDeep([{ username: "Test User 3" }]);

If you don't mind updating, I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Right you are! Updated.